# Model item passed into the dictionary is of type X, but this dictionary requires a model item of type X

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a `ViewModel`. For my app, I want to show a list of customers where there is an error present on their account. The error is stored in the database by another program.

The ultimate intention is to periodically send a message to the customers that have an error for items within their account (we're dealing with vehicles, so an example might be where the number plate check has come back with a problem and needs customer action).

I created a `ViewModel` called CustomerAlerts.cs

```
using MyProjectName.Models;

namespace MyProjectName.ViewModels
{
    public class CustomerAlerts
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> companynames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I created a controller CustomerAlertsController.cs.

```
private TestDB_FleetCompany_Dashboard_Entities db = new TestDB_FleetCompany_Dashboard_Entities();

public ActionResult Index()
{

    var viewModel = new CustomerAlerts
    {
        companynames = (from v in db.Vehicles.Include(v => v.Company)
                        where v.Issue != null
                        select new { customernames = v.Company.Name }).Select(v => v.customernames).AsEnumerable()
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

At the top of my view I have

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProjectName.ViewModels.CustomerAlerts>
```

I want to show a list of company names that are affected (I was going to add a column for the count of vehicles with issues against them later).

```
@foreach (var affected in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayForModel(affected.companynames)</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}
```

When I try to run everything I get the following message back:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'MyProjectName.ViewModels.CustomerAlerts', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyProjectName.ViewModels.CustomerAlerts]'.

Whilst I'd love a solution or bit of help, I'd appreciate a pointer on what I should be reading to help me figure out the solution for myself.

I tried:

```
return View(viewModel.AsEnumerable());
```

But this causes a "does not contain a definition for AsEnumerable" error.

Comment: I fixed it, but [please do not put tags in your question titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/189763).

Comment: Sorry. Noted for next time.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a single instance of `CustomerAlerts` to your view, but your view's model type is a collection of `CustomerAlerts`.

Either pass a collection of `CustomerAlerts`, or change your view model type to:

```
@model MyProjectName.ViewModels.CustomerAlerts
```

Comment: Thanks - this was just the clue I needed. Changing the view model type was the answer for me coupled with a change to my code in the foreach statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are returning a single instance of your `CustomerAlerts` from your `Index` method and your view expects a list of it.

Answer (score 0):

As per @devdigital above the answer that worked for me was to change the view model type to:

```
@model MyProjectName.ViewModels.CustomerAlerts
```

I did try this before, but was missing something else in the view that was causing an exception. The foreach statement needed some adjustment to this:

```
@foreach (var companyname in Model.companynames)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@companyname</td>
        <td>@companyname.Count()</td>
    </tr>
}
```

This now shows a handy list of the companies carrying errors and how many vehicles in their inventory are in an error state.